# Android Studio - Firebase storage not updating correctly

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to make a database of users with profile pictures(stored in storage) related to their IDs.

I'm using Firebase auth,Realtime database and Realime storage.

The code work like this : In user registration process, they choose username and picture. The database is filled with Users -> userUUid -> username and URL of picture stored.

The storage stores the picture.

If I keep such name of the table (Users) code works fine, however if I try to manipulate the tables, for example if I want to make more categories like Users -> SpecialUsers / NormalUsers -> userUUid -> ... the app just crashes.. I tried debugging but saw no errors.

Is there any way how to catch these Firebase exceptions (if there is any) or any explanation why if I change the structure of the tables, the code doesn't work ?

These is the method responsible for the registration :
(this one works)

```
public void signUp(String email,String password,String userName)
{
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {

        if (task.isSuccessful())
        {
            dbReference.child("Users").child(auth.getUid()).child("userName").setValue(userName);

            //if user choose some picture
            if(imageControl)
            {
                UUID randomID = UUID.randomUUID(); //create random UUID for the picture
                final String imageName = "images/"+randomID+".jpg";
                storageReference.child(imageName).putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        StorageReference myStorageRef = firebaseStorage.getReference(imageName);
                        myStorageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                String filePath = uri.toString();
                                dbReference.child("Users").child(auth.getUid()).child("image").setValue(filePath).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                        Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Write to database is successful.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                        Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Write to database is not successful.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                dbReference.child("Users").child(auth.getUid()).child("image").setValue("null");
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "There is a problem.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

This doesn't work :

(As you can see the only thing changed is the structure of the tables from only 'Users' to 'superUsers' -> 'anotherCategory')

```
public void signUp(String email,String password,String userName)
{
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {

        if (task.isSuccessful())
        {
            dbReference.child("superUsers").child('anotherCategory').child(auth.getUid()).child("userName").setValue(userName);

            //if user choose some picture
            if(imageControl)
            {
                UUID randomID = UUID.randomUUID(); //create random UUID for the picture
                final String imageName = "images/"+randomID+".jpg";
                storageReference.child(imageName).putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        StorageReference myStorageRef = firebaseStorage.getReference(imageName);
                        myStorageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                String filePath = uri.toString();
                                dbReference.("superUsers").child('anotherCategory').child(auth.getUid()).child("image").setValue(filePath).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                        Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Write to database is successful.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                        Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Write to database is not successful.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                dbReference.("superUsers").child('anotherCategory').child(auth.getUid()).child("image").setValue("null");
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "There is a problem.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

I suspect that the errors occurs somewhere after imageControl check.

In the second example of the code, the tables superUsers -> anotherCategory tables are created in the database, however the reference to the picture UUids is empty (not even null is placed)

What could be the error if nothing relevant to the process of storing pictures is changed ?

Comment: "Firebase storage not updating correctly" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly doesn't work in the shared code? Do you have any errors?